# Ping.SendAsync() always successful, even if client is not pingable in cmd

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, ping

I try to ping some IP addresses in C# using Ping.SendAsync() method. I have a treeView with 5 IP addresses and use the SendAsync() method for each node. Here you can see:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(".");
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(50, true);
    AutoResetEvent reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_Complete);

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        ping.SendAsync(node.Text, 5000, buffer, options, reset);
    }
}

private void ping_Complete(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs k)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        PingReply reply = k.Reply;

        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            node.Text = node.Text + " (OK)";
        }

        else
        {
            node.Text = node.Text + " (FAILED)";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the ping is always successful. I got 2 clients which were online and pingable. The other 3 are offline and not pingable (in cmd I couldn't ping these clients). So it should display this:

```
IP1 (OK)
IP2 (FAILED)
IP3 (FAILED)
IP4 (OK)
IP5 (FAILED)
```

But the output is 5 times "(OK)".

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: You shouldn't be able to have multiple async pings in-flight at the same time (on the same Ping instance). SendAsync throws an InvalidOperationException if you do.

Comment: You seem to have an issue with the logic: you have no way of figuring out the ping instance that is calling the ping_Complete event handler. Remember that the order in which you initiated the calls may not be the order in which you receive the response.

Comment: Just to check if this is a synchronization issue, change your method to use ping.Send()

Comment: @Tyler ,if like me , you are a beginner in TPL I recommend watching this video : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B319#fbid=

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Jon has the correct explanation to your problem.

My suggestion is that you use the `SendPingAsync` method instead; it returns a `Task<PingReply>` which you can await (you also need to make your method asynchronous):

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(".");
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(50, true);
    AutoResetEvent reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_Complete);

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(node.Text, 5000, buffer, options, reset);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            node.Text = node.Text + " (OK)";
        }

        else
        {
            node.Text = node.Text + " (FAILED)";
        }
    }
}
```

(note that this approach requires .NET 4.5)

---

As pointed out by mike z in the comments, the approach above will perform the pings serially, not in parallel. If you want to do them in parallel, you can do something like that:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(".");
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(50, true);
    AutoResetEvent reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_Complete);

    var tasks = List<Task>();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        var task = PingAndUpdateNodeAsync(ping, node);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task PingAndUpdateNodeAsync(Ping ping, TreeNode node)
{
    var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(node.Text, 5000, buffer, options, reset);
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        node.Text = node.Text + " (OK)";
    }
    else
    {
        node.Text = node.Text + " (FAILED)";
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely looks nicer, but its going to serially ping each IP which is going to be kind of slow if a few are down.

Comment: `await Ping.SendPingAsync()` throws an error: "The await operator can only be used within an async method". But SendPingAsync() is an async method, I'm a bit confused about this error.

Comment: @Tyler: Are you *sure* you're using `SendPingAsync` rather than `SendAsync`? Those are different methods.

Comment: @Tyler, did you add the `async` modifier on your method as I did in my example? The error message refers to your method, not the one you're calling.

Comment: @mikez, that's a good point. I'll update my answer to suggest another approach.

Comment: The updated code is nicer but you should wait for all of your tasks to finish before you see the result.How about having a task that updates its node status when it finishes pinging ?

Comment: @Beatles1692, you're right. I updated my answer again.

Comment: I didn't see the async modifier, thanks for that. Can someone please explain me why the second answer is nicer than the first?

Comment: @Tyler, the first code example will ping the IP addresses one by one; the second example will ping them all in parallel, and display the results as they are available.

Answer (score 8):

Every time you get *any* `PingCompleted` event, you're updating *all* the nodes in your tree the same way. Instead, you should only update the node corresponding to the IP address that the particular `PingCompletedEventArgs` corresponds with. You might want to use the node itself as the "state" argument in the `SendAsync` call, so that you can use it in your event handler.

My guess is that you're either getting failures and then updating everything with successes, or you're not waiting long enough to see the failures.

Just to validate that this is diagnostically correct, I suggest you separately log `reply.Status` somewhere that won't be overwritten.

Additionally, you're currently updating the UI from a non-UI thread, which is a very bad idea. You should marshal back to the UI thread before updating it.

Comment: Thank you for the input. What do you mean by "marshal back to the UI thread before updating it"?

Comment: @Tyler: I mean that you should only execute `node.Text` in the UI thread. There are *lots* of resources on working with threads in Windows Forms - is suggest you have a look for them.

Answer (score 1):

Fix Code:

```
private void ping_Complete(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs k)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        PingReply reply = k.Reply;
        if(reply.Address.ToString()==node.Text)
        {
           if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
           {
            node.Text = node.Text + " (OK)";
           }

           else
           {
              node.Text = node.Text + " (FAILED)";
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A better option would be to use the userToken parameter to pass the node, and retrieve it in the event handler via k.UserState. It would avoid the loop.

Comment: By debugging this code I'd seen that reply.Address is always the first IP address. So I've an issue in my loop I think. But I couldn't find the issue